# System of Linear equations that contain variables

Tags: matrices

So far all I'm seeing is a load of answers that assume the variables I'm talking about are, in fact, the linear variables you ignore when creating a matrix. But I cannot find ANYWHERE how to solve a matrix that contains a variable.

ie:

[ 1 -1  0 |  1]
[ a  4 -9 |  8]
[-2  1  3 | -5]

How would I determine what 'a' is?

Comment: Have you learned Gaussian Elimination (row-reduced-echelon-form)? Also, you would solve this to find what $a$ is not, in other words, $a$ is a free variable and what you really want to know is if there are restrictions on what it can be. Here is an example (and there are many on the site) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476022/system-of-linear-equations-with-dependence-on-a?rq=1. Regards

Comment: Here is another example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308692/finding-the-values-of-a-and-b-in-a-matrix?rq=1

Comment: You can treat a variable just like any other number: it follows the same arithmetic rules. The only difference is that you must take a few precautions. For example, you can only divide by a variable if you restrict it's domain to exclude zero.

Comment: Is it really $a$ to be determined?

Answer (score 2):

Using Gaussian Elimination, we find the solution as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{6(a+6)}{a+1} - 6 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \dfrac{6(a+6)}{a+1} - 7 \\0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{2(a+6)}{a+1} \end{bmatrix}$$

Do you see which values of $a$ would cause a problem?

Note, we can also sometimes look at the determinant of the system, we have:

$$\det(A) = 3(1+a)$$

Do you see a value of $a$ that will cause a problem?

Otherwise, $a$ is a free variable and we can choose any value we like.